# Typescript React empty function as defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a Stateless Functional Component with an optional function parameter as property (onClick), I tried to define an empty function as default property to be able to do safely in my component :

```
 <span onClick={props.onClick} />
```

But I have the following error : 'Expression expected.'

```
interface IProps {
  size?: sizeType;
  onClick?: (e:any) => void;
}
const Foo: React.SFC = (props: IProps) => {
  // ...
};
const defaultProps: IProps = {
   size: 'default',
   onClick: () => void <-- Expression expected.
};
Foo = defaultProps;
```

How can I should do this?

Comment: Can you please add the code of `IProps` to your question?

Comment: I added the interface

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
const defaultProps: IProps = {
   size: 'default',
   onClick: () => void(0)
};
```

Answer (score 33):

You cannot use `void` in javascript as return value. Instead of void, use `null` as return value.

```
onClick: () => null
```

Answer (score 6):

I think using lodashes noop might be a good option because depending on the number of re-renders the component will have BEFORE the component has access to the prop, it will create that many references to an anonymous function that essentially is a place holder for the function you need.  Something like:

```
import noop from 'lodash/noop';
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  myfunc: noop,
};
```

Its a small optimization but also prevents the developer from creating an anonymous function for every default prop declaration that a func is needed in.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  someNoop: f => f
}
```

as something that is short, easy to type, and will just return `undefined`.